# Manage date-time visualization of a dataframe with matplotlib and jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to pandas and matplotlib and I have a dataframe in the form of

```
                            Info    Temp
2022-06-06  16:34:51,389    DEBUG   55 
2022-06-06  16:34:51,482    DEBUG   56
2022-06-06  16:34:51,581    DEBUG   57
```

Using `pd.read_csv('debug.log', sep=' ')` it correctly shows the dataframe and automatically recognize the time and the day

Now, I'm able to plot the data with no issue using `table['Temp'].plot()`
The problem is the graph is super small and the data in the x-axis are overlapped.

[image]

Is there a way to make the x-axis labels rotated and zoom in the graph? I've tried `plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()` but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so just using `table['temp'].plot(rot=45,figsize=(100,10))` and right-clicking I can see the graph with a decent size

[image]

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) if needed